# TSQL merge 2 dataset with even number of rows next to eachother

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What I am trying to accomplish:

```
    Dataset 1
    Name1
    Name2
    Name3

    Dataset 2
    Number1
    Number2
    Number3
```

will become 2 columns:

```
dataset1   dataset2
Name1      Number1
Name2      Number2
Name3      Number3
```

My datasets 1 & 2 will always have equal rows.
Which name linked to which number I don't care as long as two names are not linked to the same number and vice versa.

How can I solve this with SQL / SQL Server ?

Comment: Or you using different queries for these dataSets or different SPs

Comment: Just two different queries. Select Names from NameTable, SELECT Numbers from NumberTable for example
.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the reason you need this kind of table join? What kind of data does your table contain, since it does not matter how records are linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to add an identity column to the tables, you can use the ROW_NUMBER() function like this:

```
SELECT
    T1.Col1,
    T2.Col1
FROM
    (SELECT Col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS N FROM Table1) T1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS N FROM Table2) T2
ON T1.N = T2.N
```

Here, replace Table1 and Table2 with the name of your tables, and replace Col1 with the name of the column (or columns) that you want to output from the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

Add identity columns to both the tables and perform join on basis of these column

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
  ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL


ALTER TABLE Table2
  ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL


SELECT Table1.dataset1col , Table2.dataset2Col
From Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
     ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. However I can not alter the datasets. So it has to be done on query time. I also can use rank functions and join on that. Any more pragmatic, elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you :

```
;WITH cte1 (name, rn)
     AS (SELECT Name,
                row_number()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY Name) rn
         FROM   Dataset1),
     cte2 (Number, rn)
     AS (SELECT Number,
                row_number()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY Number) rn
         FROM   Dataset2)
SELECT name,
       Number
FROM   cte1
       JOIN cte2
         ON cte1.rn = cte2.rn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH Table1 AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Dataset1) as Rnk,Dataset1
  FROM TA1
)

With Table2 AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Dataset2) as Rnk, Dataset2
  FROM TA2
)

Select Table.Dataset1 as 'DataSet1', Table2.DataSet2 as 'DataSet2'
From Table1 
inner join Table2 on Table1.Rnk = Table2.Rnk
```

Because you haven't added table name so I considered it as TA1 and TA2.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing the query is:

```
select row_number() over (order by Names asc) as rownum,
       Names
into  #Temp1
from NameTable

select row_number() over (order by Numbers asc) as rownum,
       Numbers
into  #Temp2
from NumberTable

select Names, Numbers
from #Temp1
inner join #Temp2 on #Temp1.rownum = #Temp2.rownum
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/AKFQ94599)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible solutions to this.

**First:** Use following trick (Warning: Use this in case of small datasets)

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl1.col1, tbl2.col2
FROM
   (SELECT FirstName AS col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName) Number FROM dbo.User) tbl1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT LastName AS col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LastName) Number FROM dbo.User) tbl2 
ON tbl1.Number = tbl2.Number
```

**Second:** Use variable tables to store result temporarily. This solution is for relatively large datasets. (approx records to 100s)

**Third:**
Use identitfy field in both tables as already mentioned by mmhasannn. But i will prefer this method least, as we need to modify our DB structure.

**RECOMMENDED:** Use variable tables approach

Comment: This produces a Cartesian product of two tables.

Comment: yes, you are right. Corrected the answer to add RowNumber for join